# How to assign a certain number value to a specific text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, numbering

I have a column of 300 different entries and a neighbouring column which numbers these entries.

And then I have another column consisting of same entries in different order. How do I make the initial numbering correspond with the entries in different order?

This is a screenshot how it's supposed to look like.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use **INDEX** and **MATCH** functions to lookup the text and return the number.

If your data starts from column A, your numbers are at 3rd column, based on the screenshot.

So type the following formula in column C and copy it down:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$300,match(D1,$B$1:$B$300,0))
```

If you want to get text according to numbers, then use column D with following formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$300,match(C1,$A$1:$A$300,0))
```

You can find more information about **INDEX** and **MATCH** in [INDEX & MATCH](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/index-match-better-way-look-data/)

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are looking for this, "to make the initial numbering (Sr. No. Column) correspond with the entries in different order":**

[image]

*Write this formula in Cell C2 & fill down:*

`=LOOKUP(D2,$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8)`

**Note:** *Adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Comment: Except the OP's numbers are in the columns before the text.

Comment: @fixer1234, you mean the Serial numbers 1-18 in first Column ?

Comment: Yes, those are the numbers, and the OP wants those numbers before the text in another column that's in a different sequence.

Comment: @fixer1234, ok got it now posting with corrections,, THanks lot you prompted me.

Comment: IN LO Calc, I just get a #DIV/0! error on every line.

Comment: But for me Excel 2013 is working nicely Screen Shot is part of the Sheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80110/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-fixer1234).